# Как правильно произносить слово "скомпрометировать"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно произносить слово "скомпрометировать"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Особую орфограмму составляют слова с Н   в середине корня некоторых заимствованных слов. Данная орфограмма связана не с исчезновением звука, а с произношением **«лишнего» звук Н** в сочетаниях вида **АНТ или АТ, ЕНТ или ЕТ**. Такое произношение считается **ненормативным**, но  встречается в речи.

Буквенный состав слова **проверяется по словарю**, но для решения орфограммы можно запомнить следующее условное  (эмпирическое) правило  (очень удобное): **Если возможно  двойное произношение (с Н и без Н), то Н не пишется (и не произносится); если произношение без Н невозможно, то Н пишется и произносится**, например:

1) Константа (постоянная величина), комментировать (давать разъяснения по ходу действия) – произношение без Н невозможно, Н пишется и произносится.

2) Констатировать (подтверждать факт), **компрометировать** (выставлять  невыгодном свете) – возможны оба варианта произношения, Н здесь лишнее, то есть не пишется и не произносится.

Answer (score 1):

Произносить так: [скъмпръм'Иэ'т'иръвът'].  [Н] перед [Т'] вставлять не нужно. Ударный слог -ти-.

Comment: Возможно, стоит добавить, что [ъ] это сверхкраткий звук [а], который чем-то похож на [ы].